# Postman (NodeJS): Not saving cookies returned from api

Tags: node.js, django, api, rest, postman

> Issue:

Cookies were earlier *getting **saved*** until I reinstalled Postman.

I have literally tried everything (stackoverflow + google), I would really appreciate the help.

URL : *http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup*

Settings:

[image]

Interceptor connected like:

[image]

Idk what settings are changed after installation. I'm stuck in my development process because of this.

Comment: what cookies? like sessionid or something?

Comment: YEs, I am sending back JWT + cookies attached in the req.session. It was working fine until i updated the postman. Could you help?

Comment: So you're sending cookies from django and that's not being saved in postman?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: Can you please check set-cookie in headers has the cookie value?